# Where is the Syntax error in this VB.net code?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am working on a project for university, and we've just started to learn about VB.net. We're tasked with making a form that pulls data from a mock database and acts like the University's registry/student space where they can see what module's are being taken, DOB etc...

We keep getting the error code:

> Syntax error in UPDATE statement.

Each time that we try to run a part of the form whereby we register a student for a new module. Below is the code we are trying to run to achieve this.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim sqlString As String = "UPDATE [Student] SET module = @module, moduleName = @moduleName, credit = @credit, moduleLeader = @moduleLeader WHERE studentID =" & frmMenuOptionsStudent.lblStaffNo.Text & "'"
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlString, conn)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@module", ComboBox1.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@moduleName", TextBox2.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@credit", TextBox3.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@moduleLeader", TextBox4.Text)

    Try
        conn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("New Module Added")
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

We suspect that it might be an easy fix, but we simply cannot find the error! Help! :(

Comment: `studentID ='"` missing a tick... Use a param for the where and you wouldn't have that...

Comment: Why arent you using a parameter for the Where clause like you do the others?  It would prevent the missing tick problem you have

Comment: Now, click the checkmark next to the answer that the nice man gave you,

Comment: Next time, write out sqlString to debug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Module is a [reserved word in MS-Access](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe?CorrelationId=c818043e-4276-41e0-b9c5-13fa695b2b2c&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). You need square brackets around it

```
Dim sqlString As String = "UPDATE [Student] SET [module] = @module, ....
```

By the way, I can't understand why you use parameters for every field but not in the WHERE clause. Just use them everywhere. This would have avoided the other error caused by the missing quote around the WHERE condition's value.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate this explanatory answer, as opposed to all of the downvotes lol. Bearing in mind we've had two 1 hour tutorials on VB.net and been left to it, I don't think we've done too bad lol

Comment: Don't make a big deal about downvotes. Follow the rules explained in the [help]. Do your due diligence in searching and post always a bit of code explaining your problem. A little step every day and your reps will start to improve